# eclipse - class find editor - source not find

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have a problem with eclipse debugging. I had a proper working code and few hours ago I add one more external library to do something new. When I run the program now it works properly, but when I want to debug it, it stopped on the first line of a new part of the code (the one using the newest external library). It shows the info:

"Class File Editor
Source not found
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ModelBuilder.class"

When I try to step over I just receive the same information but connected with other files. After stepping over a multiple times I finally get back to my code and can debug the rest of the program normally.
Of course I can do it always but does anybody know the solution to that problem, not to click step over multiple times but debug normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not enter the external library code unless you step into it, or there's an exception in that code.  If you find yourself stepping through code you don't have source to, use Step Return, which jumps to the end of whatever method you're in.

If it is caused by an exception in the library code and you want to ignore it, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Debug and uncheck "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions".

If you know what exception is causing the execution to suspend, then you could also try this:

1. Go to the Debug perspective
2. Open the Breakpoints view
3. Click the J with the exclamation point by it (J!)
4. Search for the exception that triggers the debug suspend
5. Uncheck the two check boxes
6. Say OK

Comment: Even if I put the breakpoint after the line I was talking about, debugger will show the message I was talking about. Now, I am dealing with that with resuming and noticing if I already get out of the problematic line. clicking Step Return take a lot of time to get out of this message (because than show another with different files like I've written). But the point is why this problem happens, not how to deal with it, and I have no idea...

Comment: Which class are you in when you see that message, a class you have code for, or a class in a library that you don't have code for?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like exception. I think I have wrong configured debugger but I checked many things and nothing helped.

Comment: Go to the debug perspective, look for the Breakpoints tab, and delete all the breakpoints (the double-X).  Then add back the one breakpoint that you want it to hit in your code and try again.

Comment: Sorry, checking it more carefully it looks like an exception. Before first "resume" it is a "NullPointer" but later are other different. But I am sure that the code is written properly and I know that I used to use it that way once a few months ago and it worked. That is why I think it is the configuration problem.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to the Window menu entry at the top, then click on Preferences.  Along the left-hand side, find Java and click the triangle to expand the entries under that.  From there, select Debug.  You should see "General settings for Java Debugging" along the top.  There are a series of check boxes.  Find the one by "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions" and uncheck it.

Comment: That was pretty clearly described what to do. ;) Unfortunately I did it and nothing changed...

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?  I would go back and double-check that there are no other breakpoints set (using the Breakpoints view in the Debug perspective) and that the setting I described is unchecked.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much. :) It helped, I didn't notice few breakpoints which still left. :) Thanks again and have a nice day. ;)